# php array Calendar Mo-Sun with roomnumbers and guests or noguests inside

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table

so, I would like to create a roombooking calendar view of Mo-Sun that looks like this:

|  | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Room1 | First Guest | First Guest | First Guest | First Guest | ------ | -------- | ------ |
| Room1 | Second Guest | ------- | --------- | Second Guest | Second Guest | Second Guest | Second Guest |
| Room2 | First GuestRoom2 | First GuestRoom2 | --------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | ------ |
| Room2 | ------ | Other GuestRoom2 | --------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | ------ |
| Room2 | ------ | Another GuestRoom2 | --------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | ------ |
| Room2 | ------ | Last GuestRoom2 | --------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | ------ |
| Room3 | Only GuestRoom3 | Only GuestRoom3 | Only GuestRoom3 | -------- | ------ | -------- | ------ |

**Option:** When I click on the name, it opens me a  edit-site for the Bookingdates of the guest OR

- Room1 has a capacity of 2 guets
- Room2 of 4 guests
- Room3 of 1 guest

**Doing**
So I need an array: Calendar Mo-Sun with roomnumbers and guests or noguests inside

My first try was this idea (I hope I could write it understandable):
I want to build a multidimensional array "$calendar" step by step, which contains a room occupancy per weekday with name of guests or "free" as a text. The array contains weekday Mon-Sun, room name and maximum capacity of occupancy (chairs).

```
Array [Monday] => Room1 ->"First Name", "Second Name";
=> Room2 -> "Third Name", "free", "free", "free";
=> Room3 -> "Last Name";
[Tuesday] => Room1 ->"First Name", "Second Name";
=> Room2 -> "free", "free", "free", "free";
=> Room3 -> "Third Name";
// and so on
```

I have tried this with:

````
//Weekarray of weekdays:

$Week = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");

//Rooms has the Name of the Roomnumber and max. Guestcount:

$Rooms = array("Room1"=>2, "Room2"=> 4, "Room3"=> 1);
$roomnames = array_unique(array_keys($Rooms))

$counter = 0;
do
{
    $Calendar [] = $Week[$counter]; //Weekday Mo-Sun write in array

    $roomcounter=0;
    do                              //Array of "Monday" get roomnames in the same count as max amount Guestcount per room
    {
        $Calendar [$Week[$counter]][] = $roomnames[$counter];
        $roomcounter++;
    }while ($roomcounter < $Rooms[$counter]);
    
    $counter++;
}while ($counter < 7);``` 


But I get an Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings  and  Undefined offset:
Is my way the right way?
What could I do better?
Why I couldn't generate such an array in this way?
Could you help me, plese? :-)
````

Comment: What line gives that error?

Comment: Error **"Undefined offset"** is at:
68:  }while ($roomcounter < $Rooms[$counter]);
70: $counter++;

Error **"Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings"** is when I trie to write something like that:

$Calendar [1][]= "hallo";